# Touch began func saying touch is never used

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uikit

I have the code below and I am trying to make the pig on my screen move so I added a touch began function.

When I added in the function, it said that touch was never used and that I should replace it with a `_`. What am I doing wrong?

```
import SpriteKit
import UIKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    var porker:Porker!
    var touchLocation = CGFloat()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        addBG()
        addPig()        
    }

    func addBG() {
        let bg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bg");
        addChild(bg)
    }

    func addPig() {
        let Pig = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "pig")
        porker = Porker(guy:Pig)
        addChild(Pig)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
       /* Called when a touch begins */

         func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
            touch = touches.first!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you've put a function within a function.... delete the inner function...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches{
// code goes here
 }
}
```

Comment: Could you add some details of your code how addresses the problem(s) in the question? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Remove the double up of touchesBegan.

```
import SpriteKit
import UIKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    var porker:Porker!
    var touchLocation = CGFloat()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        addBG()
        addPig()        
    }

    func addBG() {
        let bg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bg");
        addChild(bg)
    }

    func addPig() {
        let Pig = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "pig")
        porker = Porker(guy:Pig)
        addChild(Pig)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first!
        // do something with your touch
    }
}
```

Comment: when you added "touch =  touches.first" it said that im using an unresolved identifier being touch